# How To Insert this mongodb document to collection using postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman, body-parser

I tried My Collection Structure like this is in node

```
app.collection('person').insertOne({
    name: req.body.name,
    details: [{
        age: req.body.details.age,
        town: req.body.details.town
    }]
});
```

In Postman I tried Like This

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "details:[ {
        age: "1",
        town: "efg"
    },
    {
        age: "2",
        town: "jkl"
    }]
}
```

I get null values in my result. I need to know how to send this data to mongodb using nodejs with postman

Comment: Can you post a more complete sample?

Comment: Insert Array of object using postman . post like this in postman {name:"abc",details:[{                               
        age: "1",
        town: "efg"
    },
    {
        age: "2",
        town: "jkl"
    }}]},                                                                                                     i want to post the object present in detail array using postman

Comment: I mean a more relevant snippet of your application. The object needs to get somehow (generally through an endpoint) to your running application so it can get persisted.

Comment: I Have Array details:[] inside the array I want to insert some objects. In postman i send the data as details:[{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}].my problem is how to write code in node for this. I write like this in postman {details:[{a:req.body.details.a,b:"req.body.details.b"}] }, when I write like this i got null value in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can update your update query implementation to match incoming request payload mapping the `req.body.details` directly to the document `details`field:

```
app.collection('person').insertOne({
    name: req.body.name,
    details: req.body.details,
});
```

Otherwise you have to use `Array#reduce` to transform your input array to match your desired storage structure.